# TypeError: expected string or buffer while using regular expression in python

Tags: python, html, regex, beautifulsoup

I wrote this code to remove the tags that match like this

`<p><b>See also:</b> <a href=\"(.*?)\">(.*)</a>(.*)</p>`

**CODE:**

```
import mechanize
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
med = 'paracetamol'
listiterator = []
listiterator[:] = range(2,16)
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
r=br.open("http://www.drugs.com/search-wildcard-phonetic.html")
br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form['searchterm'] = med
br.submit()
url = br.response().geturl()
print url
mainurl = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
subpages = re.findall("<a href=\"(.*?).html\">[^>]*>", mainurl)
for sub in subpages:
    if sub.startswith("http:"):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(sub).read())
        m = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"contentBox"})
        head = m[0].find_all(["h2","p"])
        for i in head:
            m = re.match("<p><b>See also:</b> <a href=\"(.*?)\">(.*)</a>(.*)</p>").group()
            if not m:
                print i         
        break
```

I got this error:

```
m = re.match("<p><b>See also:</b> <a href=\"(.*?)\">(.*)</a>(.*)</p>",i).group()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 137, in match
    return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3001761

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get that error because the type of the variable `i` is `<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>`, and `match` needs a buffer or string. Secondly, if the pattern doesn't match, then the `.match` call will return `None`, so your `.group` will be a null pointer exception.

Here's a *quick and dirty* "solution" I don't recommend:

```
m = re.match("<p><b>See also:</b> <a href=\"(.*?)\">(.*)</a>(.*)</p>", str(i))
if not m:
    print i
```

A better solution would be to rewrite without trying to parse HTML yourself, letting BeautifulSoup do its job. For example, instead of your regex pattern, exclude the items that contain the text `See also` and an anchor tag:

```
if i.find(text='See also:') and i.find('a'):
    continue
print i
```

Comment: What are the chances that `str(i)` formats the html *exactly* as your regex expects? (ignoring the fact that it uses a regexe to parse html text while using the html parser to unparse its structures into raw html instead of using the built tree).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I don't know. And I don't recommend it.

Comment: @janos: obviously, yours *"I don't recommend it"* has no effect on OP. `str` is quicker, easier, more seductive.

Answer (score 0):

`.find_all(['h2', 'p'])` returns `Tag` objects but `re.match` expects a string. Don't call `re.match` on `Tag` directly. `BeautifulSoup` allows you to pass regexes to `.find*()` methods.