# Why do I get "expected string or buffer," when I am working with strings?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am working with Python's re.sub function. It's throwing a TypeError: "expected string or buffer." After debugging and adding plenty of assert statements to check that I am passing strings to re.sub, I am still unsure about why I am getting the exception. Below, please see: my code, the error stack, and other related questions I have perused.

```
import json
import re
import string
def readFile(filename):
    p = re.compile('[1-9]*[1-9]')
    def n2w(_string):
        isInt = True
        stringToReturn = ""
        try:
            stringToReturn = num2words(int(_string))
        except:
            stringToReturn = _string
        assert isinstance(stringToReturn,str)
        return stringToReturn
    def convertNumbersToWords(_string):
        #Error: expected string?
        assert isinstance(_string,str)
        _string_copy = p.sub(_string,n2w)
        return _string_copy
    questions = []
    articleTitles = []
    articleTexts = []
    answers = [] # Stores questions and article titles and article contents and their associated answers, which are stored as strings.
    # I can access the questions by using [:,0]
    #TODO: Find a way to store questions and article content as keys.
    # TODO: Convert unicode to string.
    #NOTE: I use questions_answers rather than articleTitles_answers because articles can have multiple answers.
    with open(filename) as file:
        data = json.load(file)
        articles = data["data"]
        # Iterate through articles, looking for question/answer pairs.
        for article in articles:
            article_title = str(article["title"].encode('utf-8','replace')) # Converts Unicode object to string.
            article_paragraphs = article["paragraphs"]

            article_text = "".join([str(paragraph["context"].encode('ascii','replace')) for paragraph in article_paragraphs])
            if (len(article_paragraphs) == 0):
                print("O")
            for paragraph in article_paragraphs:
                qas_pairs = paragraph["qas"]
                # Check if this paragraph has questions.
                if (len(qas_pairs) == 0):
                    print("O")
                for qas_pair in qas_pairs:
                    # Note: There's another attribute called "context", which may come in handy.
                    answer = qas_pair["answers"][0]
                    answer_text = str(answer["text"].encode('ascii','replace')) # Converts Unicode object to string.
                    # Get where to find the answers.
                    #answer_start = answer["answer_start"]
                    #answer_end = answer_start + len(answer_text) - 1
                    question = str(qas_pair["question"].encode('ascii','replace'))
                    # Replace numeric characters with English words.
                    question = convertNumbersToWords(question)
                    answer_text = convertNumbersToWords(answer_text)
                    article_title = convertNumbersToWords(article_title)
                    article_text = convertNumbersToWords(article_text)
                    # Remove special characters.
                    from string import punctuation
                    question = question.strip(punctuation)
                    answer_text = answer_text.strip(punctuation)
                    article_title = article_title.strip(punctuation)
                    article_text = article_text.strip(punctuation)
                    questions.append(question)
                    articleTitles.append(article_title)
                    articleTexts.append(article_text)
                    answers.append(answer_text)
    print("All done")
    extractedData = np.array(questions,articleTitles,articleTexts,answers)
    return extractedData
```

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 trainingData = readFile("train-v1.1.json")
>         2 from sys import getsizeof
>         3 print("Finished loading training data.")
>         4 print("Size of training data:",getsizeof(trainingData))
>
> in readFile(filename)
>        51                     question = str(qas_pair["question"].encode('ascii','replace'))
>        52                     # Replace numeric characters with English words.
>   ---> 53                     question = convertNumbersToWords(question)
>        54                     answer_text = convertNumbersToWords(answer_text)
>        55                     article_title = convertNumbersToWords(article_title)
>
> in convertNumbersToWords(_string)
>        16         #Error: expected string?
>        17         assert isinstance(_string,str)
>   ---> 18         _string_copy = p.sub(_string,n2w)
>        19         return _string_copy
>        20     questions = []
>
> TypeError: expected string or buffer

**Other questions**

[TypeError: expected string or buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16193521/typeerror-expected-string-or-)
[TypeError: expected string or buffer while using regular expression in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22574770/typeerror-expected-string-or-buffer-while-using-regular-expression-in-python)
[python re.search error TypeError: expected string or buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22896914/python-re-search-error-typeerror-expected-string-or-buffer)

These questions specifically address a situation where a regex function is receiving strings; since I have done the legwork to ensure this is true, I feel these questions are irrelevant.

Comment: The arguments are in wrong order: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.sub

Comment: @KlausD. Oops! I guess it follows the logic: "substitute ___ for ___"  - this may be the first Python function I've seen where the affected object isn't the first argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, you may want to change `_string_copy = p.sub(_string,n2w)` to `_string_copy = p.sub(n2w,_string)`. In addition, it would help if you can also provide a sample of your JSON file. Then, though not sure what you want, you might consider changing `extractedData = np.array(questions,articleTitles,articleTexts,answers)` to `extractedData = np.array([questions,articleTitles,articleTexts,answers])`

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains instruction: `_string_copy = p.sub(_string,n2w)` and the other
answer suggests to change it to `_string_copy = p.sub(n2w, _string)`.

I agree with that (the first parameter should be the replacement expression),
but I spotted another detail raising my doubts, concerning `n2w` function.

Look e.g. at https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html - a documentation
of *re* module and find fragment *If repl is a function*.

The next sentence states: *The function takes a single **match object** argument*,
but in your code `n2w` function has a **_string** as a parameter.

Unfortunately, I'm unable to reproduce the error, since I have no
input file, so I limit my post to just making you aware of the above
discrepancy.

Maybe you should change the parameter to **match** (match object) and rework
the content accordingly? The string just matched you can obtain with
`_string = match.group()`.

I spotted also such a weird detail in `p = re.compile('[1-9]*[1-9]')`:

Look at the regex. It contains:

- `[1-9]*` - a sequence of digits (1 to 9), possibly empty,
- `[1-9]` - another (single) digit.

Why didn't you write just `[1-9]+`? It means just the same (a non-empty
sequence of digits), but is shorter and less complicated.